# Suppose $|G| < \infty$ and $H \leq G$ such that the product of any two left cosets has the same cardinality as $H$. Is $H$ is normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

In class, we showed that if $H \leq G$ is not normal, then there exist $a, b \in G$ such that $(aH)(bH) \neq abH$. In particular, we showed that if $y \in (1 \; 2) \in S_3$, then for $H = \langle y \rangle$ and $x = (1 \; 2 \; 3) \in S_3$, we have: $(1H)(xH) = \{x,xy,x^2y,x^2\}$, so the product has a different finite cardinality than $H$.

Then I thought of the question in the title of this post. I think it's false, but I cannot come up with a counterexample. Any hints?

**Edit:** By the product of two left cosets, I mean the point-wise product: $(aH)(bH) = \{xy : \; x \in aH, y \in bH\}$

Comment: What is the product of two left cosets?  If $H$ isn't normal this isn't well defined.  (Unless you mean the point-wise product, as in $AB =\{ab | a \in A, b \in B\}$.

Comment: Yes, I meant the point-wise product: if $H \leq G$, then $(aH)(bH) = \{xy : \; x \in aH, y \in bH \}$. Thanks for asking, I will clarify this in the post.

Comment: I'm not native English speaker: does the "any" in the title mean "some" or "every"?

Comment: @Devo it means "every"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YES.

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements in $G$. Note then that $a$ is in $aH$. Thus the relation $(aH)(bH) \supseteq abH$ holds. That the equation $|(aH)(bH)| = |H|$ holds as well however, gives the equation $(aH)(bH)=abH$ for all $a,b \in G$. So now let $h$ be an arbitrary element in $H$. Then the equation $(aH)(bH)=abH$ holds implies that there is an $h' \in H$ such that $ahb= abh'$.

Thus, for any $b \in G$ and any $h \in H$, the equation $hb = bh'$ holds for some $h' \in H$. This implies normality of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: I don't see that $(aH)(bH) \subseteq abH$.  An arbitrary element in the left looks like $ahbh'$.  How do I get that in $abH$?

Comment: I think you have the containment the wrong way round. It is clear that $abH \subseteq (aH)(bH)$ because $1 \in H$. So $|(aH)(bH)| = |abH|$ implies $abH = (aH)(bH)$ and $H$ is normal.

Comment: Ah, Derek Holt figured it out.

Comment: Yes, I got the inclusion relationship backwards. Good catch!

Comment: @Mike well, that looks easy! thanks for the reply!

Comment: Glad I could help!